# PHP - How to populate a variable in another class

Tags: php

How to populate a variable in another class? Help anyone? 
From Class1 and Class2 need to store data in class Template.
Thank you.

[My example classes](http://pastebin.com/DmmAVpe0)

Answer (score 2):

You can create some setter. Example for $data_class_1_a :

```
<?php
class Template
 {
      private $data_class_1_a;
      private $data_class_1_b;

      // ...

    function setDataClass1A($value) {
        $this->data_class_1_a = $value;
    }

      // ...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. I can not understand, you even closer to your code? Please power.

Comment: With `$obj = new Template();` use `$obj->setDataClass1A('myvalue')` to set the field $data_class_1_a to 'myvalue'.

Comment: Solution does not work :-( Internal Server Error...

Comment: No it works http://pastebin.com/JdxihVuE. Pastebin your code.

Comment: But it does something else than required :-(

Comment: Pastebin your error or create a new question.